# Why is retrofit reordering my QueryMap params?

Tags: android, retrofit, github-api

I'm trying to query the github api like so...

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=created:>=2015-07-11&sort=stars&order=desc&perpage=25&page=1
```

Here is my GET

```
    @GET("/search")
    public void getTrending(@QueryMap Map<String,String> filters,Callback<GitResponse> response);
```

Here is how I setup my query Map...

```
    Map<String,String> searchFilters = new HashMap<>();
    searchFilters.put("created>","2015-07-11");
    searchFilters.put("sort","stars");
    searchFilters.put("order","desc");
    searchFilters.put("perpage","25");
    searchFilters.put("page", "1");


   api.getTrending(Collections.unmodifiableMap(searchFilters), new Callback<GitResponse>() {
       @Override
       public void success(GitResponse gitResponse, Response response) {
           Log.e("tag",response.toString());
       }

       @Override
       public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
           Log.e("tag",error.toString());
       }
   });
```

Here is the url that gets formatted by retrofit.

https://api.github.com/search/repositories?order=desc&created>=2015-07-11&perpage=25&sort=stars&page=1

Notice that the order of the params is not retained. I need the `created >=` to be the first param for the query to work correctly. I tried using `Collections.unmodifiableMap()` but that didn't help. In the [retrofit docs](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/http/QueryMap.html), they are using guava's `ImmutableMap.of()`. Do I HAVE to use guava for the order to be retained?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is not related to retrofit at all. You have a floating order because `java.util.HashMap` doesn't guarantee order. You should use `LinkedHashMap` instead to get fixed elements order.

You better to know how hash map works by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm a little late but anyway... :)

The point of named parameters is that the order doesn't matter. If it matters the server is faulty.
Your main problem seems to be that the parameter's name is not "created". It's "q". "created" ist part of the value.