# How to add array of strings into HashMap<String, String> and then send with Retrofit?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit 2 for sending API calls to server, but with parameters I need to send array of strings which must be excluded from API response.

I need to send parameters like deviceToken, feedType and also send an array of excluded strings, so my URL with exclude strings should look like this:

```
http://test.com?test[]=1&test[]=2&test[]=3
```

Of course there are other missing requirements.

Take look at this line of code:

`params.put("exclusions",  Arrays.deepToString(arr));`

Here is my code:

```
@GET("enquiry/user-feed/")
Call<UserFeed> userFeed(@QueryMap Map<String, String>   params);

HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

params.put("deviceToken", getDeviceToken());
params.put("feedType", feedType[0]);
params.put("feedOrder", order);
params.put("feedLimit", String.valueOf(limit));   

Log.d("TAG", "exclusions: : "+ Arrays.deepToString(arr));
params.put("exclusions",  Arrays.deepToString(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to retrofit al all. You have a floating order because java.util.HashMap doesn't guarantee order. You should use LinkedHashMap instead to get fixed elements order.

source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31748890/1949658

Comment: Why LinkedHashMap? The problem is that I can not add string array to hash map that accepts string for key and value

Answer (score 0):

use LinkedHashMap

```
LinkedHashMap<String, String> params = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

params.put("deviceToken", getDeviceToken());
params.put("feedType", feedType[0]);
params.put("feedOrder", order);
params.put("feedLimit", String.valueOf(limit));
```